# Feed input to intermediate layer and then do back propagation in keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, backpropagation, multiview

I have looked around everywhere but could not find the way to do this.
Basically I want to feed input to some intermediate layer in a keras model and want to the backpropagation for the full graph (i.e. including layer before the intermediate layer). To understand this I refer you to the figure as mentioned in the paper "**Multi-view Convolutional Neural Networks for 3D Shape Recognition**".

[image]

From the figure you can see that the feature are maxpooled in view pooling layer and then the resultant vector is passed to the rest of the network.
From the paper they further did he back propagation using the view pooling features.

To achieve this I am trying a simple approach. There will not be any viewpooling layer in my model. This pooling I will do offline by taking the features for multiple views and then taking the max of it. Finally the aggregated feature will be passed to rest of the network. However I am not able to figure out how to do the back propagation to the full network by passing input to intermediate layer directly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an intermediate layer?

Comment: As you can see from the figure the layer before the CNN2 is the intermediate layer. Basically I will get the features after CNN1 and take the max of it for every object finally the maxpooled feature will be passed to the CNN2. In this figure first layer of CNN2 is the intermediate layer

Comment: OK. I am still not sure if I understand why you want to do this. Why don't you feed in your images through CNN1 and do backpropagation as usual?

Comment: Because we have to take max pool for all the views of an object. Basically view pooling layer takes the maxpool for the images which belong to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the code of the tensorflow model, then this will be quite simple. The model would probably look like

```
def model( cnns ):

    viewpool_output = f(cnns)  
    cnn2_output = cnn2( viewpool_output )
    ...
```

You would just need to change the model to

```
def model( viewpool_output ):

    cnn2_output = cnn2( viewpool_output )
    ...
```

and instead of passing a "real" view pool output, you just pass whatever image you want. But you haven't given any code, so we can only guess at what it looks like.

Comment: Hello bremen. I got your point. And I tried doing similar to this. Only problem is how do I save the model viewpool_output and cnn2_output separately. Since in the first model definition if you print the model summary there are no separate entities as viewpool_output and cnn2_output, it will be a continuous graph instead. Therefore later when I want to pass the viewpool_output to cnn2 how do I restore the later part such that when I train it the cnn before viewpool_output also get the gradient. I hope you understand my point. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: ANd by the way there are no multiple cnns before viewpool. It is the same model which is used multiple times to get features for each view which is then maxpooled to obtain the final representation for the 3d object.

Comment: There are a few options here if you just want to train the part after the view pooling, but then later add it back in...

Comment: 1. You can insert a tf.stop_gradient after the view pooling so that nothing before it is trained.

Comment: 2. For all of the variables in the layers before view pooling, you can set trainable=False

Comment: Hello bremen. I want the layers before viewpooling to be trained. That is the main problem. If I wanted only later half then I can make a separate model of later half and then I can initialize its weight from the full model and then train it separately. The problem is then the layers before viewpooling will not be trained as done in the paper.

Comment: Then you need to update your question. It is still not clear exactly what you want